# Select previous text field of a clicked element

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following table, with one row, two columns, in one column i have a text field, in the other one a simple button, i haved the text field 'disabled' and i want to enable it the button is pressed...

```
 <table id="tabla_busqueda">  
 <tr>
     <td><input type="text" value="2"></td>   //This text field is disabled
     <td><button class="editar_campo">Click Me</button></td>
 </tr>
 </table
```

i have the following:

```
 $('body').on('click', '#tabla_busqueda .editar_campo', function(){

    $(this).prev('input[type=text]').removeAttr('disabled');

});
```

but it's not working

any ideas why?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements are wrapped in `td`, so you'll need to do some more traversing, and use prop() :

```
$('body').on('click', '.editar_campo', function(){
    $(this).closest('td')
           .prev('td')
           .find('input[type="text"]')
           .prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: thanks, this work perfectly, but why do you target first 'closest' and then 'prev'??

Comment: Yup. There is only one element in the table data cell and so the previous search will come up with a length of 0. The first parent tier must be searched.

Comment: @kastulo - the button is inside td, so when clicking the button we first find the closest() parent td, then target the previous td, and the find the input inside that td.

Comment: @kastulo - nope, prev gets the previous element, you need to get the parent, which you'd do with parent(), parents() or closest(), I prefer the latter.